Determine the rank of powers of a matrix with 1's on the first superdiagonal
I am self-studying through a text on linear algebra and encountered the following problem:

Let $A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathsf{M}_n$ and suppose that
\begin{equation}
a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } j = i + 1, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Determine the values of rank $A^k$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.

Here is my attempted solution:

Note that the matrix $A$ consists of ones on the first superdiagonal, and zeros everywhere else. For instance, for $n = 4$,
\begin{equation*}
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
 \end{equation*}
Observe from this that the columns of $A$ have the form
\begin{equation*}
  A = [0 \; e_1 \; e_2 \; \ldots \; e_{n - 1}] = [a_1 \; a_2 \; \ldots \; a_n].
 \end{equation*}
Now, observe that $Ae_1 = a_1 = 0$, and that for $1 < j \leq n$, $Ae_j = a_j = e_{j - 1}$.
> Now, I claim that for $0 \leq k < n$,
\begin{equation*}
  A^k = [\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0}_{k \text{ times}} \; e_{1} \; e_2 \; \ldots \; e_{n - k}].
 \end{equation*}
Base Case: ($k = 0$): $A^0 = I = [e_1 \; e_2 \; \ldots \; e_n]$ satisfies the required form.
Inductive Step: Assume that for some $0 \leq k < n$,
\begin{equation*} 
A^k = [\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0}_{k \text{ times}} \; e_1 \; e_2 \; \ldots \; e_{n - k}].
\end{equation*}
Then, note that
\begin{align*}
  A^k &= AA^k \\
   &= A[\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0}_{k \text{ times}} \; e_{1} \; e_2 \; \ldots \; e_{n - k}] \\
   &= [\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0}_{k \text{ times}} \; Ae_{1} \; Ae_2 \; \ldots \; Ae_{n - k}] \\
   &= [\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0}_{k \text{ times}} \; 0 \; e_1 \; \ldots \; e_{n - k - 1}] \\
   &= [\underbrace{0 \; 0 \; \ldots \; 0 \; 0}_{k + 1 \text{ times}} \; e_1 \; \ldots \; e_{n - (k + 1)}].
 \end{align*}
This proves the claim. Moreover, note that this induction implies $A^{n - 1} = [0 \; \ldots \; 0 \; e_1]$, meaning $AA^{n - 1} = A^n = 0$ and thus $A^k = 0$ for $k \geq n$.
From this, we find that $A^k$ has $n - k$ linearly independent columns. These columns thus form a basis for $\text{col } A$, and hence $\text{rank } A^k = n - k$ for $k \leq n$, and $\text{rank } A^k = 0$ for $k > n$.

While I believe the spirit of this solution to be correct, I think the proof needs significant cleaning up. In particular, I'm having trouble writing the induction, since the behavior of incrementing the power $k$ for $k < n$ "pushes" the $e_i$ columns to the right, but for powers of $k$ greater than or equal to $n$, we have the zero matrix (so raising the power does nothing). These are two different behaviors (before and after the "cutoff" at $n$), and it's difficult to put them into a single proof by induction.
I am wondering how this proof might be cleaned up and made more rigorous. Alternative approaches to this problem are also welcome (although, for the sake of my solution, I intend to only use the basic facts/definitions about matrix algebra, basis, dimension, and rank).

I am a very picky marker of student work. I would be satisfied with the rigour of your proof. It is a bit clunky, but not excessively so. I suppose I could write a proof of the fact that "The set ${e_i \mid i>k}$ is a basis of the image of $A^k$ for every $k\geqslant 0$", but don't think you should waste time on that. Onwards!

Thank you for the feedback!
